# Finding data in element using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to find the element  “Dropchord” inside a `<h2>` element on Craigslist.

Example HTML:

```html
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal" title="Dropchord" href="http://www.amazon.de/Double-Fine-Productions-Dropchord/dp/B00E0OK2X2/ref=sr_1_2?s=mobile-apps&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1427809716&amp;sr=1-2&amp;keywords=AS-Productions">
  <h2 class="a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal">Dropchord</h2>
</a>
```

I've tried many things, such as:

```js
try {
   //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("(//h2[contains(@class, 'a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal')])"));
   //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("//h2[@ class='a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal']"));
   //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.CssSelector("h2[class='a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal'])"));
   //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.CssSelector("h2.(a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal)"));
   //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.CssSelector("h2"));
   IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath(".//h2"));
   //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//h2[text()='Dropchord']"));
   //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.CssSelector("//a[@ class='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal']//h2 [@ class='a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal']"));

    foreach (IWebElement Name in AppName){
        if (Name.Text == appname){
            // ...
        }
    }
} catch {

}
```

I cannot yet post the image. but it can be [found here](http://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Dmobile-apps&field-keywords=AS-Productions).

Comment: <a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text normal"
title="Dropchord"
href="http://www.amazon.de/Double-Fine-Productions-Dropchord/dp/B00E0OK2X2/ref=sr_1_2?s=mobile-apps&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1427809716&amp;sr=1-2&amp;keywords=AS-Productions">

<h2 class="a-size-base a-color-null
s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal">
Dropchord
</h2>
</a>

Comment: I can not yet post the image. but here is the URL

http://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Dmobile-apps&field-keywords=AS-Productions

I use Firefox

Thanks

Comment: Hi,LittlePanda i don´t understand your question. what do you think?

Comment: Sorry wrong comment....deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select.FindElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='atfResults']//h2"));
```

Comment: I have this Exception "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" Please can you tried with my URL and tell me when it woking    Thanks

Comment: I tried the following code and it returns with all of the h2 tags:
    this.driver.get("http://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Dmobile-apps&field-keywords=AS-Productions");
    List<WebElement> titles = this.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='atfResults']//h2"));
    for(WebElement title : titles) {
      System.out.println(title.getText());
    }

Comment: If it is still doesn't work for you, could you please copy, what is **select** in your code? Thank you

Comment: thank you all of you
I replacing select with driver. it works  thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code has a extra `)` in the end. After removing that shloud work for you.

   ```
   IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("(//h2[contains(@class, 'a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal')]"));
   ```
2. text() cannot be used as follows

   ```
    IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//h2[text()='Dropchord']"));
   ```

instead use it as follows:

```
IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//h2[contains(text(),'Dropchord')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u please try with xpath like:

> //a[@title='Dropchord']/h2

in here u can see that the a tag containing h2 element is having title="Dropchord" and its child is h2.

Comment: It is not working. the cursor goes directly on the catch function()

Comment: Can u please provide the exception or stacktrace? And please dont post parts of your question as an answer. edit it in question itself or comment it to the concerned persons answer.

Comment: @Maeva what is select? is it an element or driver instance?

Comment: select is a FirefoxWebElement

Comment: so u r looking into select element,when the elements are not available. please refresh the webelement by again firing driver.FindElement on select element, then use the provided xpath or css. The exception u r getting is cause the elements are not available in DOM object of webdriver coz the page has refreshed .

Comment: I do this               driver.Navigate().Refresh();
                                IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("//h2[contains(@class, 'a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal')]"));
                                //IList<IWebElement> AppName = select.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@title='Dropchord']/h2"));              Ibut I get the same problem